# How to effectively dynamically store data to DataTable

Tags: c#, sql, database, datatable, datagrid

I'm trying to dump data into `DataGrid` that I have stored in DB. I would like it to be automatically saved in the DB when new data comes in. The method that collects the data is in one class and the `DataGrid` is in another. This way, I know how to solve it. Simply move the methods to one class and whenever a new object is added to the DB, it is added to the `DataGrid`. But I don't like this solution and I would like to make it so that I don't have to put methods into one class. But for the life of me I can't figure out how to do it. Maybe create a static `DataTable` object in the class where I collect the data? But isn't that again a clumsy solution?

> Method where I am collectiong data

```
  for (int i = 0; i < inbox.Count; i++)
                    {
                        var message = inbox.GetMessage(i, cancel.Token);
                            GetBodyText = message.TextBody;
                        Problem problem = new Problem(message.MessageId);
                        if (!dAOProblem.GetAll().Any(x => x.Message_Id.Equals(problem.Message_Id)))
                        {
                            dAOProblem.Save(problem);
                            Alert alert = new Alert(message.MessageId, message.Date.DateTime, message.From.ToString(), 1, problem.Id);
                            if (!dAOAlert.GetAll().Any(x => x.Id_MimeMessage.Equals(alert.Id_MimeMessage)))
                            {
                                dAOAlert.Save(alert);
                                count = dAOAlert.GetAll().Count();
                               
                            }
                          
                        }

                    }
```

> Method where are data displayed

```
 public void LoadAlertGrid()
        {
            SqlConnection con = DatabaseSingleton.GetInstance();
            using (SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("SELECT Alert.email , Alert.date , AMUser.name as 'admin', Problem.nameOfAlert, Result.result " +
                "FROM ((Alert INNER JOIN AMUser ON Alert.AMUser_ID = AMUser.id)" +
                " INNER JOIN Problem ON Alert.Problem_ID = Problem.id " +
                "INNER JOIN Result ON Problem.Result_ID = Result.id); ", con))
            {
                DataTable table = new DataTable();
                SqlDataReader sdr = comm.ExecuteReader();
                table.Load(sdr);
                AlertTable.ItemsSource = table.DefaultView;
                sdr.Close();
            }
            
        }
```

Comment: `I would like to make it so that I don't have to put methods into one class`...why? It sounds like logically they belong together. If you know it would work that way then why are you making life difficult for yourself?

Comment: I don't like when I am putting too much code into one method

Comment: In the question you said you didn't want to put 2 methods in one class, not that you didn't want to put too much code in one method, those are different things. If they belong in the same class logically then they should go there. It sounds like you are inventing arbitrary rules about this (and not particularly consistent ones at that) instead of being practical.